# How do I make this time countdown work in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I'm trying to add a time countdown for my website. I first made one on my own which worked perfectly in Chrome but not in firefox or IE. So I instead decided to look one up and found a promising one. Once again this one worked perfectly in Chrome but not in IE.

This is the javascript countdown I'm using: http://trulycode.com/bytes/easy-countdown-to-date-with-javascript-jquery/

In Chrome it displays a fully functional countdown while in IE it just produced "00 00 00 00" or alert message "Invalid date. Example: 30 Tuesday 2013 15:50:00". 
I'd be really happy if someone could help me get this countdown work for all web browsers.

When trying it in IE I get the following message in the debugging console: 'interval' is undefined File: testcountdown, Line: 176, Column: 4. 
This is line 176: interval = setInterval(i, 1e3).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post a jsfiddle example of your problem.

Comment: Which IE version? It works on IE 9.0.8112.16421

Comment: This is how it works in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fQ6VB/ .
I have IE 11.0.9600.16518 installed.

Comment: Those are some really awful selectors in that script, I'm surprised it works at all.

Comment: Well, I have no idea what the problem with this code is. That's why I expressed it like that.

Comment: @nullability What do you mean? They're all class selectors

Comment: I just tested in IE 7 and the website doesn't work. And I just looked and the website uses jQuery 2.0.3, which isn't supported in IE < 9. But the fiddle posted in these comments does work for me in IE 7

Comment: @HenrikSandstrom: What debugging have you done? Why is your code posted on another website, and not here? Have you narrowed the problem down at all?

Comment: When trying it in IE I get the following message in the debugging console: 'interval' is undefined File: testcountdown, Line: 176, Column: 4. This is line 176: interval = setInterval(i, 1e3).

Comment: @HenrikSandstrom I'm finally reading the JS in the fiddle. Declare all the variables that are being set without being declared first

Comment: I don't think this little library is worth your time. It's very poorly written. I'm sure you could find a better one or write a better one.

Comment: If it matters, I added/changed some things and got it working. Because of the overall poor quality, I still wouldn't suggest it unless it were cleaned up a lot more. Here's it working in IE 11: http://jsfiddle.net/7K8xA/show/ (remove the "show/" at the end of the URL to view the code)

Comment: Thank you so very much Ian it's working now. Since you're saying it's poorly written I might still try to find a better one. Thanks again.

Answer (score -3):

From jQuery [website](http://jquery.com/download/): "jQuery 2.x has the same API as jQuery 1.x, but does not support Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8. "

Just change to a previous version of jQuery.

Comment: Like I wrote in the comment above, I tried it in IE 11. Which didn't work.

Comment: This is actually the right answer. The website uses jQuery 2.0.3, and the website doesn't work for me in IE 7. (obviously the problem). The fiddle created in the OP's comments does work for me in IE 7 (has jQuery 1.*

Comment: @Ian: What does IE7 have to do with it?

Comment: @Ian: I know, but what does IE7 have to do with this question?

Comment: @cookiemonster The title is "How do I make this time countdown work in IE?". If the OP is using the library they linked to, with jQuery 2.* (like the website does), it won't work in IE < 9. The solution is to downgrade to jQuery 1.*. If the OP is using IE >= 9 and the script doesn't work, there's another problem.

Comment: @Ian: The OP has commented twice that IE 11 is the version being used. That's why this answer is wrong and is getting downvoted.

Comment: @cookiemonster Why didn't you say that the first time? The OP commented **once** that they're using IE 11, and I didn't even realize that was the OP's comment (oversight on my part). And the OP's jsFiddle is using jQuery 1.* anyways, so the version of jQuery shouldn't be the problem (again, oversight by me)

Comment: @Ian: Two oversights? ;-) [first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261684/how-do-i-make-this-time-countdown-work-in-ie#comment33813708_22261684) ... [second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261684/how-do-i-make-this-time-countdown-work-in-ie#comment33813857_22261835) I thought maybe you were seeing some IE7 reference that I was missing.

Comment: @cookiemonster COME ON. I give up. Haha too many oversights. And the OP needs to debug more because they and I are getting errors in developer tools for IE 11

Comment: @Ian: Yeah, I think it's kind of a drag when some guy finds code online, finds out it's crap, then comes here to have someone else fix it. OP should definitely be doing some debugging.